# Looping through the index of an array

Tags: ruby

I am working on a Ruby script that will download emails from Gmail and download attachments matching a specific pattern. I am basing this off the excellent [Mail gem](http://github.com/mikel/mail) for Ruby. I am using Ruby 1.9.2. I am not that experienced with Ruby and appreciate any help offered.

In the code below, emails is an array of emails returned from gmail that contain a specific label. What I am stuck on is looping through the array of emails and processing what may be multiple attachments on each email. The inner loop of emails[index].attachments.each does work if I specify an index value, I have not been successful in wrapping the first loop to go through all the index values of the array.

```
emails = Mail.find(:order => :asc, :mailbox => 'label')

emails.each_with_index do |index|
    emails[index].attachments.each do | attachment |
      # Attachments is an AttachmentsList object containing a
      # number of Part objects
      if (attachment.filename.start_with?('attachment'))
        filename = attachment.filename
        begin
            File.open(file_dir + filename, "w+b", 0644) {|f| f.write attachment.body.decoded}
        rescue Exception => e
            puts "Unable to save data for #{filename} because #{e.message}"
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the syntax for `each_with_index` is like this:

```
@something.each_with_index do |thing,index|
    puts index, thing
end
```

You should then replace the line 
    emails.each_with_index do |index|

with

```
emails.each_with_index do |email,index|
```

However I don't see you actually using the index so you could probalby simplify it to this:

```
emails.each do |email|
    email.attachments.each do | attachment |
....
```

Comment: ahhh, the simplicity. I love Ruby. Too much javascript I suppose, got attached to using the index. Thanks @Andreas.

Comment: same. js developer confused why `arr.each do |x, i|` wasn't working!

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter yielded to the block by each_with_index is the object, not the index.

```
emails.each_with_index do |o, i|
  o.attachments.each do | attachment |
```

And unless you need the index in code we haven't seen, you could just use the `each` method there.